# Magento 2. customer_entity , customer_address_entity purpose of prefix, suffix columns?

Tags: magento2

What is the purpose of the **prefix** and **suffix** columns on the **customer_entity** and **customer_address_entity** tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Prefix** and **Suffix** column are use for add title before and after customer name.

For Ex.

> Prefix : The title that goes before name (Mr., Mrs., etc.)
>
> Suffix : The suffix that goes after name (Jr., Sr., etc.)

Answer (score 1):

**When you Add Customer in Magento Admin Panel:-**

[image]

Prefix: The title that goes before the name (Mr., Mrs., etc.)

Suffix: The suffix that goes after name (Jr., Sr., etc.)

You have two Text Field "**Prefix**" And "**Suffix**". This is Two columns saved in this table `customer_entity`.